# Using Q_ASSERT in constructor

Tags: c++, qt, constructor, qt4, assert

I need to ensure that a certain pointer passed to my constructor is not `NULL`.  Normally I just put a `Q_ASSERT()` at the beginning of the function like this:

```
void Class::doStuff( Object *object )
{
    Q_ASSERT( object );
    // do stuff
}
```

But since the constructor is a special function, I would like to know if this same technique is kosher.  Is there anything wrong with using Q_ASSERT in a constructor like this?

```
Class::Class( Object *object, QObject *parent = NULL ) 
    :
QObject( parent ),
_object( object )
{
    // make sure that object is not NULL
    Q_ASSERT( object );

    // do stuff that will dereference the pointer, hence it must not be NULL
    if( object->hasSomething() )
        // do stuff
}
```

If this is bad practice, what would be the right way to check for `NULL`, ideally at time of construction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Q_ASSERT` in constructor is OK. There is no reason why it's not. It just prints a message to the output.

Comment: Well, usually it asserts and aborts the program. Then it doesn't matter if it was in a ctor or not ;)

Answer (score 0):

This really depends how and where your code is going to be used. You are right that constructor is a special function and best practices is

1. to use as minimum external functions and calls ( outside of your code base) in it and
2. NOt use calls that may throw expceptions. It is because when exceptions are thrown, there is unwinding of the stack happening to clean up before exiting your app and calling the proper catch call.

Well, if it is in a constructor, the state of the that particular object is not clear with regard to what has been done and what need clean up and such. So at the end of the day it is your call to see if that is an issue in your case.